# Scala Play Framework Slick - type mismatch issue

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick, play-slick

I'm following [this](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/sql.html) documentation, trying to put together a simple query:

```
package models

import scala.slick.session.Database
import Database.threadLocalSession
import scala.slick.jdbc.{GetResult, StaticQuery => Q}
import javax.sql.DataSource
import Q.interpolation

object Data {

    case class User(user: String, password: String)

    lazy val db = Database.forName("default")

    implicit val getUserResult = GetResult(r => User(r.<<, r.<<))

    def result: Option[User] = {
        db.withSession {
            sql"SELECT user, password FROM user WHERE user = 'user' AND password = 'pass'".as[User]
        }
    }

}
```

Problem is, the row

```
sql"SELECT user, password FROM user WHERE user = 'user' AND password = 'pass'".as[User]
```

throws these errors:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - type mismatch; found : scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery0[models.Data.User] required: Option[models.Data.User]
    - type mismatch; found : scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery0[models.Data.User] required: Option[models.Data.User]
```

What am I missing here?

Scala 2.10.3, Play Framework 2.2.0, Slick 1.0.1

**UPDATE:** Solved:

```
sql"SELECT user, password FROM user WHERE user = 'user' AND password = 'pass'".as[User].firstOption
```

Comment: Try adding `.firstOption` after `.as[User]`? According to [these docs](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/0.11.0/api/index.html#scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery0) that'll convert a `StaticQuery0[R]` into an `Option[R]`, which you want to do there.

Comment: @Mikesname Didn't like it, the error changed to: `value headOption is not a member of scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery0[models.Data.User]`

Comment: Sorry I meant `.firstOption`.